# How to deactivate secure boot on windows 8.1 when uefi firmware settings arent available?

Tags: windows-8.1, secure-boot

I've installed Windows 8.1 in UEFI mode, screen that proves it is below

[image]

After rebooting system in advanced mode going to:

Troubleshoot->Advanced options

I can't find UEFI Firmware settings tile in here.

Searched through several threads but no one helped me.

Is there any other way to disable secure boot?

Comment: Is there an option in your UEFI settings before you get to Windows?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable `secure boot` in bios settings.

This option should be available there.- just look for it.